# Android launcher icon crops into my icon image

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, icons

I build my Android app with VS2017 Xamarin, but I'm not sure that has anything to do with my problem. I have built an app icon (PNG) that looks like this:

[image]

But when I launch my app in an Android emulator, it always crops out some of my icon, thusly:

[image]

Notice that a bit of the truck tires and truck top get cropped out. But this makes no sense because as you can see in photoshop, there is plenty of empty space between the truck icon and the edges of the square. I want that space/margin to be preserved inside the icon, and not so aggressively cropped.

[image]

I keep adding more and more space, but something (Android OS? Xamarin compiler? VS2017?) seems to be ignoring the margin/space and trying to aggressively crop right up to my icon.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should Adaptive icons above Android 8.0.https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Comment: Thank you Junior...but in reading through that it seems enormously complex for a simple little icon. Can you possibly summarize what I need to do to make my app icon look as expected? If I put a physical circle around the truck icon, will that solve it? And which of the mipmap folders contains the actual launcher icon?

Comment: Hi, the easy way you can refer to Saamer's answer and check if have mipmap folder in resource.Here is a image for reference.https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrGXZ.png

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps - I already have all the pngs in the various mipmap folders. I need to know how to make an image that doesn't get cropped so close to the center.

Comment: Okey,I want to know first how much the total size of the icon is, and how much is the size of the middle truck image.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your app is trying to look for a Round Icon file as you can see in this [Microsoft blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/round-launcher-icons-in-android-7-1/). The easiest way to solve all your Icon issues for Android, including the pesky adaptive icons, is to use Android Studio. You just install the free application (Windows/Mac) and then

1. Open the Android Studio, and create a blank project. Then right click on the resources folder of the project and add an “Image Asset”.
2. In there, add the image, and then resize the image appropriately. Press OK.
3. Reveal the file in Finder/Explorer and Migrate all the files and folders to your existing project in Visual Studio.
4. For rounded icons to work, you might have to make changes to the manifest file, or what ever file in the app you set the icon image name, and add an attribute of rounded-icon like in the article
5. Test it & it should work